# Failed template inheritance in django templating

Tags: django, django-templates, template-inheritance

I am in a middle of a project. The project uses basic html at the frontend. I having trouble in template inheritance.
This is the basic code : -

```
    {% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Home</h4>
    <hr>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        {% block home %}{% endblock home %}
    {% else %}

    {% for doc in doctor %}
        <div>
            <small>Doctors around</small>
            <br>
            <a href="{% url 'profile' doc.user.id %}"><li>{{doc.user.name}}</li></a>

            <br>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Also the code is extended to another template.
The child page is :-

```
    {% extends 'rec/home.html' %}
{% block home %}
    <div>
        {% if request.user.usertype == 'p' %}
            <h1>Hi {{request.user.name}} </h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Hi {{request.user.name}} </h1>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

{% endblock home %}
```

Both the files are in the same directory. But i have defined the templates dir in settings file in a different directory.

When i do tree /a at the templates directory this is what i get :-

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 6A82-72DF
E:.
  \---rec
```

Comment: do two things. **#1** make sure you're authenticated. **#2** using cmd go to the templates dir , do `tree /a`  and give us the output- you can clean it up if you want

Comment: Provided the results in the edit

Comment: I was thinking it might have been a retaliative path issue, all paths should be full from **templates/** - but it all looks good! I have no freakin idea, and I've done this before: 3 extends (main -> section -> page) ..so no errors and it's just not showing up.. hard one

Comment: Yep no idea why its not working

Answer (score 0):

<s>It's just `{% endblock %}` you don't have to specify what block you're closing / I'm not sure you even can</s>  **Wrong**

That's the only issue I see with what's provided

Comment: You can and it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the template to extend from in each template, maybe try doing something like this:

**Template.html**

```
{% extends parent_template %}
```

**Views.py**

```
template = loader.get_template('app/page.html')
context = {}
context["parent_template"] = "app/parentPage.html"
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

This way you can assign the template from the Django side and it should be easier to troubleshoot